# How are normal people supposed to persist settings in a Windows Phone 8 app?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I'm in the process of writing a Windows Phone 8 app, so I can capture that much sought-after 3% market share, and am having a hard time persisting user settings within the application.

I first ran across [this blog](http://windows-mobile-dev.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-uses-isolated-storage-api-in.html) which goes over the basics of the Windows.Storage namespace, which is intended to do exactly this sort of thing.  Yay!

However, I guess the author never actually *ran* his own code, as otherwise he would know that the second you call `ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings`, you'd get a `NotImplementedException` exception.  [To the MSDNs we go!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings)

Well, this makes it pretty clear that this API is not implemented on Windows Phone 8.  I came to this conclusion when it said, "This API is not implemented and will throw an exception if called." - Well that's great.

So, maybe there's some other similar APIs.  After a bit more Googling, I came across [this blog](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-8-Apps-The-8-Must-Know-Tricks-Day-6.aspx).  It's called "Windows 8 Apps - Must Know Tricks!".  This looks official!  It goes over all sorts of *really cool looking* persistence APIs, including permanent and transient storage, roaming storage, etc.

But guess what: `RoamingFolder`, `RoamingSettings`, `TemporaryFolder`, `LocalSettings` - None of it is implemented on Windows Phone 8.

Did implementing these somewhat-key features just slip their mind?  Am I supposed to create a local SQL database to store basic app settings, or is there something simple I'm not finding?

Comment: "normal people" ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ah ha!  Figured this out.  I dug up the Windows Phone 7 API docs, and the legacy APIs actually still work on Windows Phone 8 as well.

```
public static void Session_PersistSession(string ticket)
{
   if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("SessionTicket"))
   {
      IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["SessionTicket"] = ticket;
   }
   else
   {
      IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("SessionTicket", ticket);
   }

   IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
}

public static string Session_LoadSession()
{
   string ticket;
   if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.TryGetValue<String>("SessionTicket", out ticket))
   {
      return ticket;
   }

   return null;
}
```

Comment: Good thing they exchanged this with the "uniform" WinRT style API... oh wait!

Comment: The IsolatedStorageSettings you found, does that roam the data? It would be great to share data between Windows Phone 8 app and Windows 8 app.

Comment: @Christian80 - Nope, doesn't roam..  There *is* a roaming storing provider, but of course it's not implemented yet on Windows Phone.  So I guess roaming is only for tablets and desktop computers?  Which is a bummer, because it would be quite cool to have settings roam on mobile apps too.  I wonder when MS plans to implement this stuff..

Answer (score 3):

A couple of options here....

1. [LocalFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Localfolder) is supported so you could serialize whatever state you want to a file there.
2. Check out the [IsolatedStorageSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class, specifically the [ApplicationSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.applicationsettings%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property

Also this may provide a bit more context: [How to preserve and restore app state for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967547%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)