# c#: Accessing Protected Class Variable From Outside Class?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I used below type of navigation in my app. i need `var page` in another class. since i used protected class, i can't call this var page. is there anyway to call this var page. Because, i need this var to initialize another class. So, how to access protected class variable from outside of the class ?

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("Page"))
    {
        var page = NavigationContext.QueryString["Page"];
        browser.Navigate(new Uri("/f" + page + ".html, UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

I need in this class;

```
    private void def(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch(page)
        {
        \\...
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to do.  Also, I don't see a class definition anywhere in your code.  Do you mean method or function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you keep that in the Windows Phone settings key,value storage.

In the first class you store it

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("Page"))
    {
        var page = NavigationContext.QueryString["Page"];
        IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

        //store it in the settings 
        if (!settings.Contains("qsPage"))
        {
            //if setting has not been created, add it
            settings.Add("qsPage", page);
        }
        else
        {
            //store a the page in the setting
            settings["qsPage"] = page;
        }
        browser.Navigate(new Uri("/f" + page + ".html", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

In the seccond class you use it

```
private void def(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //if you need to check that the setting exists use this 
    //if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("qsPage"))

    //retrieve tha value from the settings
    var page = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["qsPage"];

    switch(page)
    {
    \\...
    }
}
```

Code adapted from example found here 
**Quickstart: Working with settings in Windows Phone**
**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714090%28v=vs.105%29.aspx**

And dont forget to close the ".html" string whith doble quotes

This other answer might be helpful too

**[How are normal people supposed to persist settings in a Windows Phone 8 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558809/how-are-normal-people-supposed-to-persist-settings-in-a-windows-phone-8-app)**

Comment: I got Error : `The name 'session' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: @user2655873 sorry about the "session" mistake, the source code has been updated to use the Windows Phone (key,value) settings

Comment: I got Error as `The name 'txtInput' and 'settings' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: @user2655873 i have just edited the post to fix both errors, let me know

Comment: @user2655873 great to know that, I also learned about this thanks to your question

Answer (score 0):

By definition protected classes (or members) can only be accessed within their own class or derived classes.

Create another class that inherits the protected one, give it a public property and assign the value of "page" to that property in the constructor.

Comment: then in his second class he will need an instance to that class that needs to be initilized with a value that it does not have !!

Comment: Not from my phone, no. And @MauricioGracia has a valid point, you would have to alter other points in the code to instantiate and use the new derived class instead of using the protected base class. Now that I think further on it, if you need to access data from an instance of it then why have it protected?

Comment: @JamesBrandon i am very new to this app development. so, please explain your answer with code