# Windows Phone- How to set LocalSettings first time?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In Desktop Application or Web Projects projects there were App.configs and Web.configs files to store settings. These settings were set in development time (or whenever later) but if this occures, it was ALWAYS once action.

In Windows Phone 8.1 XAML there isn't any App.config file, so developers are able to use `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings`. Nice.

How can I set these settings **first time** (this means on first application run ever, so I can later only read them and sometimes update existing values)? Of course I can set settings whenever I run application but this is time wasting. How do you set LocalSettings in you applications first time? I saw this solution [Is there a "first run" flag in WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609412/is-there-a-first-run-flag-in-wp7) but I don't think so, that this is the only possibility.

Comment: Might Help [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

// Create a simple setting

localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"] = "Hello Windows";

// Read data from a simple setting

Object value = localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"];

if (value == null)
{
    // No data
}
else
{
    // Access data in value
}

// Delete a simple setting

localSettings.Values.Remove("exampleSetting");
```

[Msdn Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

[Persistance of Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558809/how-are-users-supposed-to-persist-settings-in-a-windows-phone-8-app)

Comment: It's not about **how to** save, read, update settings. It all about **first** settings initialization.

Comment: i was used IsolatedStorageSetting to save the first time run flag , before the wp 8.1 comes. i think u cud statically set localseettings.Values["FirstRun"]= false and when set it true for firsttime and play Introduction things and after when app open this will be "True" so we cud get its not first time. Pls correct if i'm wrong

Comment: This is not the worst idea but further it requires defining all settings in assembly (but this is another thing). Thanks for giving an idea.

Comment: @Fka, pls let me know if u have best workaround for this

Answer (score 5):

I have written code:

```
    public void Initialize()
    {
        var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

        if (!localSettings.Values.ContainsKey(FirstRunSettingName))
        {
            localSettings.Values.Add(FirstRunSettingName, false);
        }

        localSettings.Values.Add(SettingNames.DataFilename, "todo.data.xml");
    }

    public bool IsFirstRun()
    {
        var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

        if (localSettings.Values.ContainsKey(FirstRunSettingName))
        {
            return (bool)localSettings.Values[FirstRunSettingName];
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

In the App.xaml.cs file:

```
    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += this.OnSuspending;

        var storageService = Container.Get<ISettingsService>();

        if (storageService.IsFirstRun())
        {
            storageService.Initialize();
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure this is proper way to set settings first time, but it is some soultion.

Comment: this is wat i have mention above , U have made it interface driven .Nice