# C# Accept button

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am building an Universal application for Windows phone 8.1.

I have a setting page where there is only one Toggle Switch.
I have tried to find out how I can save the toggle switch state. Also after apps is closed and again opened.

This is how I try:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    if (!settings.Contains(TSwitch.IsOn))
    {
        settings.Add(TSwitch.IsOn);
    }
    settings.Save();
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), null);
}
```

Comment: You may also consider to remove TSwitch.IsOn otherwise you add it to your settings but you won't evr remove it (I assume your have specular code to load it at startup).

Comment: possible a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26798977/windows-phone-how-to-set-localsettings-first-time/26799285#26799285

Comment: That is for me or for someone else?

Comment: @makvins51374424 Is that solution not working for you ? . it seems to be the same question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
if (TSwitch.IsOn)
        {
            Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["TSwitch"] = "Set";
            Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["TSwitchValue"] = "on";
        }
        else
        {
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["TSwitch"] = "NotSet";
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["TSwitchValue"] = "off";
        }
}
```

Then in your App.xaml.cs, add:

```
        switch ((string)Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["TSwitchValue"])
        {
            case "Set":
                {
                 //Do something
                   break;
                }
           case "NotSet": 
                {
                //Do something
               break;
                }                
           default:
                {
                  //Do something 
                    break;
                }
        }
```

You can change the case options per your toggle switch requirements.

Comment: I partially don't agree with implementation: 1) yes, it's better to use new API but 2) OP has to save on/off state...why `TSwitch` and `TSwitchValue`? 3) switch/case on strings for a boolean value? Isn't better and faster `ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["TSwitch"] = TSwitch.IsOn` followed by `if ((bool)ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["TSwitch"]) { }`? No need to switch over unmaintainable literal string values (and with side-effect to have shorter code).