# How to get previous checkbox state in windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, checkbox

I have a checkbox under a listbox using the given xaml file .
My xaml file:

```
<ListBox x:Name="notificationSettingsListBox" Grid.Row="1"   Margin="20,20,20,20" Background="#e79e38"  >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="#055cc3" Width="500" Height="200" Margin="30,40,30,20">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding channel_name}" Foreground="White" FontSize="31" TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,20,10,0" />
                        <CheckBox x:Name="pushNotiOnCheckBox" Content="Enable Notification"  Checked="pushNotiOnCheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="pushNotiOnCheckBox_Unchecked"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Suppose in my listbox i have 5 checkbox and the user just checks 2 of the checkbox. Now when the user lunches the app in next time it will show the checked state of these 2 checkbox which he previously checked.

How can i achieve that using these xaml file in windows phone ??

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26798977/windows-phone-how-to-set-localsettings-first-time/26799285#26799285

Answer (score 1):

You can store the selected values in the settings. This settings are persisted by the system and you can read the values by starting your app:

Code sample (save):

```
var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

// txtInput is a TextBox defined in XAML.
if (!settings.Contains("userData"))
{
    settings.Add("userData", txtInput.Text);
}
else
{
    settings["userData"] = txtInput.Text;
}

settings.Save();
```

Code sample (read):

```
// txtDisplay is a TextBlock defined in XAML.
if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("userData"))
{
    txtDisplay.Text = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["userData"] as string;
}
```

More Infos: See [this msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj714090(v=vs.105).aspx)

Then, when you start your app/show the view: You just need to check, which values are checked in the settings and then mark the CheckBox as checked. When the Checkboxes are dynamic (not static) you better make a ViewModel to achive this.

Comment: I know that but problem is that how can i restore the checkbox state like pushNotiOnCheckBox.Checked = settings["CheckBox1Checked"] because i have a list of checkbox. @Joehl

Comment: As I mentioned: You can use the MVVM pattern and load the items in the list dynamically with a viewmodel. The view (xaml) then loads the items dinamically via a binding to the viewmodels-list. Infos about the mvvm pattern: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/gg521153(v=vs.105).aspx