# How to retain changed state of controls when windows phone app is closed and opened again

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have developed a Windows phone application where have given the user to change the theme to Light theme but when the user closes the application and re-launces the application it starts with default state that is controls again become black etc.

How do I retain the changes even when app is closed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are users supposed to persist settings in a Windows Phone 8 app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558809/how-are-users-supposed-to-persist-settings-in-a-windows-phone-8-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save a configuration setting, and apply it to the theme when your application loads. There is object that you can store key/value pairs in IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.

Here is a [microsoft example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj714090%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) which you could use to write something like this for your theme settings.

```
IsolatedStorageSettings localSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings

//save the theme when user chooses their preference
localSettings.Values["theme"] = "light";

//retrieve the user's preference
string theme = (string)localSettings.Values["theme"];
```

You may want to create a Settings class to define your settings, declare defaults, and check for nulls. There is a microsoft sample for that too: [How to create a settings page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769510(v=vs.105).aspx). Then, you can use the application lifecycle events to load your settings and theme when your application is opened

> Use the State property of the PhoneApplicationService class to store
>   transient application state in the Deactivated event handler and to
>   retrieve application state in the Activated handler.
>
> [Source -  How to: Store and Retrieve Application Settings Using Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff817009%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: can you explain me a bit on local settings and how to use it as in where to declare etc